# Swift - Hours/Minutes/Seconds to Integer conversion

Tags: ios, swift

I have Hours / Minutes / Seconds that I would like converted into an integer

7 Hours  30 Minutes 5 Seconds

Comment: *converted* from what?

Comment: I would like an Int = 27005 which is: 7 Hours 30 Minutes 5 Seconds as I'm making a time sheet which show total time, then im multiplying total time with currency i.e £10.66

Comment: (Hours * 3600) + (Minutes * 60) + Seconds

Comment: How would I display it as an Int? I very new to Swift and coding sorry.

Comment: What is your input exactly and how do you want to output the result (i.e what do you mean with "display it as an int")?

Comment: My output display is "EEEE, d MMMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm". Im constructing a timesheet so total time (I have code for) then multiply by hourly rate gives me total pay. However I need an Int output on HH:mm only to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe share some code?

Comment: can you please give more details I mean how you wants to represent hours, minutes and seconds, and how you are currently getting, and some sort of code which you are currently using in your app

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[split()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894564-split)**:

```
import Foundation

func getSecondsFromString(timeString: String) -> (Int) {
  let timeParts = timeString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", with: " ", options: [.regularExpression])
                            .split(separator: " ")
                            .map{Int($0)!}
  return timeParts[0] * 3600 + timeParts[1] * 60 + timeParts[2]
}

print(getSecondsFromString(timeString: "7 Hours 30 Minutes 5 Seconds"))
```

**Output:**

```
27005
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time difference between two dates in seconds using `timeIntervalSince` then you can directly convert this into hours as a double by doing

```
let hours: Double =  elapsedTime / 3600 // 7.501388...
```

In your examples this is 7.5 which you can then multiply with the hourly rate. If you for some reason only want to use full hours you can either round to the nearest full hour

```
let fullHours = round(hours) // 8.0
```

or if you want to truncate minutes and keep the hour then you can do a integer division from the start

```
let hours: Int =  elapsedTime / 3600 // 7
```